# Improper Integral Difficulty

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Trying to do the problem

$$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-sx}\cosh(ax)\,dx.$$

where we have the assumption that $s>|a|$ and everything is a real number.

We tried:

```
Integrate[Exp[-s x] Cosh[a x] && s > Abs[a], {x, 0, t}, Assumptions -> a ∈ Reals]
```

But did not get a response. Any thoughts?

Comment: "....we have the assumption that $s>|a|$..." -- And isn't that the purpose of `Assumptions ->...`?

Comment: `Integrate[Exp[-s x] Cosh[a x] && s > Abs[a], {x, 0, t}, 
 Assumptions -> s > Abs[a]]`

Comment: @Dr.belisarius Does anyone know how to get Wolfram Alpha give some step-by-step solutions for this problem? Tried input free form but didn't get the option of step-by-step solution.

Comment: @David Sorry. I don't use WA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Integrate[Exp[-s x] Cosh[a x], {x, 0, ∞}, Assumptions -> s > Abs[a] && a ∈ Reals]
```

$\frac{s}{s^2-a^2}$

Note that this is the Laplace transform:

```
LaplaceTransform[Cosh[a x], x, s]
```

$\frac{s}{s^2-a^2}$

Your problem was that you were trying to integrate a "function" that included the logical expression `&&` when that was actually a *condition*.